# Problem with a class setter function. Class setter function does not assign values properly

Tags: c++, friend-function

the statement below the function calling is not executed. i am at a loss, why this is so? could someone please clarify. Please consider the code below :

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cmath>
using namespace std;
class Matrix
{
private:
int row,col;
double *values;
public:
    Matrix();
    Matrix(int r, int c, double* x);
void setdim(int m, int n){row=m;col=n;}
int getrowdim() const {return row;}
int getcoldim() const {return col;}
    void set_values(int i, double x);
    double get_value(int i) const;
friend Matrix operator+(const Matrix &A, const Matrix &B);
};
Matrix::Matrix()
{
    this->row = 0;
    this->col = 0;
    this->values = NULL;
}
Matrix::Matrix(int r, int c, double* x)
{
    this->row = r;
    this->col = c;
    this->values = new double[r*c];
    for (int i =0;i<r*c;i++)
    {
        cout<<"Enter value ["<<i<<"] ";
        cin>>this->values[i];
    }
}
void Matrix::set_values(int k, double x)
{
    this->values[k] = x;
}
Matrix operator+(const Matrix &A, const Matrix &B)
{
    int rowa = A.getrowdim();
    int cola = A.getcoldim();
    int rowb = B.getrowdim();
    int colb = B.getcoldim();
   
    if(rowa == rowb && cola == colb)
    {
        Matrix C;
        C.setdim(rowa, colb);
        for(int i =0; i< rowa*cola ; i++)
        {  
        cout<<"i = "<<i<<", A.get_value = "<<A.get_value(i)<<", B.get_value =  "<<B.get_value(i)<<endl;
        double m = A.get_value(i) + B.get_value(i);
        cout<<m<<endl;
        C.set_values(i, m );
        cout<<"Returned from C.set_values()"<<endl;

// THIS STATEMENT DOES NOT GET PRINTED. PLEASE TELL THE REASON // WHY. I SUSPECT THE ERROR IS HERE

        }
        return C;
    }
    else
    {
      cout<<"Invalid Operation";
      return A;
    }
}
double Matrix::get_value(int i) const
{
    return this->values[i];
}

int main()
{
    Matrix A(2,2,NULL);
    Matrix B(2,2,NULL);
    Matrix C;
    C = A+B;
    return 0;  
}
```

The statement -  Returned from C.set_values() does not  get printed at all .

Could someone help clarify why this is the case? Thanks a lot for the help!

Comment: dont use raw owning pointers as members. If you do you need to correctly manage it. There are more issues in your code. Using a `std::vector<double> values;` as member will solve most of them

Comment: Have you used your debugger to step through the function to determine what is happening?

Comment: `setdim` sets `row` and `col`, but you still don't have any memory allocated to `coeff`.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number Would you be able to clarify where the pointers haven't been used in a nice way here?

Comment: @MathMan the default constructor sets the pointer to `NULL` but then all other methods expect it to point to an array. Thats not only "not nice" but outright wrong. In more general terms: the class is not adhering to the rule of 3/5, which is mandatory when a class manages a resource

Comment: @MathMan often beginners want to pratice the "manual way" but unfortunately it is too easy to get it wrong when one doesn't know about the rule of 3/5. Its a bit like trying to cross an ocean as your first swimming exercise (when in fact you can take a motor boat ;)

Answer (score 3):

Here:

```
    Matrix C;                             // (1)
    C.setdim(rowa, colb);                 // (2)
    for(int i =0; i< rowa*cola ; i++)
    {  
    cout<<"i = "<<i<<", A.get_value = "<<A.get_value(i)<<", B.get_value =  "<<B.get_value(i)<<endl;
    double m = A.get_value(i) + B.get_value(i);
    cout<<m<<endl;
    C.set_values(i, m );                  // (3)
```

You default construct a `Matrix` (1). The default constructor just sets the member `values` to `NULL`. Then you adjust the size members in (2), but `values` is still `NULL`. Then, in (3) you call `set_values` which tries to access array elements, but there is no array.

The problem is that your `Matrix` has a raw owning pointer as member. When a class manages a resource you must follow the [rule of 3/5](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three). If you don't, the class is broken. Managing a resource is not trivial, and following the rule of 3/5 is just the bare minimum.

The simpler alternative that you should strive for is the rule of 0. For a class that does not manage a resource, the compiler generated special members are just right. If you replace the raw pointer member with a `std::vector<double>` then you do not need to worry about copying, assignment or destruction, because the compiler will generate the required methods for you.

Comment: Great answer. Most of us started without considering the rule of 3/5 ! as that's how it is taught usually. But, really appreciate your insight

Comment: @MathMan teaching C++ is a topic on its own. Unfortunately it still is the state of the art to teach C++ as C with classes and to use C++ as a vehicle to teach pointers rather than teaching actual C++. Btw I am by no means an expert on the rule of 3/5. 99% of my classes don't need custom implementation of any of the special methods, and the other 1% is RAII classes that have a detructor but nothing else.